# How to read textfile line by line into RichTextbox

Tags: c#, text-files, richtextbox

I have a textfile which contains texts.Now as per my requirement i have to read this textfile line by line into the richtextbox.At present i am reading all lines of the text file at once into richtextbox.Here is my code ..

```
richTextBox1.Text = File.ReadAllText("E:\\vikas\\abc.txt");
```

But i want to display the texts of the textfile into richtextbox line by line.

Comment: Why would you want to read it line by line if you are assigning it to a textbox?

Comment: @BasBrekelmans my requirement is like that ?You have a problem ?

Comment: Because reading it line by line is very inefficient if you are going to put it into a single string anyway, due to immutability of strings.

Comment: Please, do not include information about a language used in a question title unless it wouldn't make sense without it. Tags serve this purpose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like

```
List<string> lines = File.ReadLines ("E:\\vikas\\abc.txt").ToList();

foreach (string current in lines)
{
    richTextBox1.Text += current;
}
```

Comment: If you just want the first line then use string first = lines[0];  If you wan't to break out of the loop then use break; but bear in mind current will no longer be available.

Answer (score 1):

not checked, but you just do something like this. you do not want to read it straight into a textbox, because that is slow!!!

```
using(StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(filename)
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    While(sr.Peek() >-1)
    {
         sb.Append(   sr.ReadLine() );
    }

    The_Textbox.Text = sb.ToString();
}
```